# Should I have a primary key for an associative table if it were to be referenced from another table

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, erd

I am creating a database for property and residential database.

Here are the requirements.

1. An owner can own many properties.
2. A property can have many owners (joint ownership with spouse, relatives, etc)

So I have an associative table since Owner-Property is a many-to-many relationship.

Owner_Property

- 1st attribute: owner id (FK to Owner table)
- 2nd attribute: property lot id (FK to Property table)

Having established that, I also need to store information about which months a particular owner stays at a relevant property.

So I thought of creating another associative entity, `Duration_of_stay_at_Property`, where first attribute is `month_id` and the other attribute will link back to `Owner_property` table, either via Fk to composite keys or a primary key which will have to be created in `Owner_property` table.

What do you suggest about the PK/composite decision?
Is there any improvement do you want to suggest the design?

Answer (score 1):

> ...need to store information about which **months** a particular **owner** stays at a relevant **property**...

This sentence openly states that you need a new entity that has a three-column composite key. Somehing like:

```
dwelling (month, owner_id (FK), property_id (FK))
```

Sometimes, when you have extra entities related to `dwelling`, then you may add an extra single-column PK in it, keeping in mind that you also need to keep the main unique constraint. Something like:

```
dwelling (dwelling_id, month, owner_id (FK), property_id (FK))
  + constraint unique (month, owner_id, property_id)
```

Comment: Ahh... I mean I already have Owner_Property table which already describe the paring, I could just use it, don't I? Why would I have ower_id and property_id attributes in dwelling? Or are you suggesting I should stick to composite keys owner_id and property_id?

Comment: That would be a terrible design. The `Owner_Property` entity represents something different; probably the "ownership contract", not multiple months a person lives in the property. For a purchase you have **one** ownership row, but can have **many** dwellling months... or zero. In this last case... you would NOT have any row?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the following solution :

- add a primary key in table `Owner_Property`
- link `Duration_of_stay_at_Property` to the primary key of `Owner_Property` (along with other informations such as the month of stay)

The rationale behind this :

- it is usually a good practice to have a primary key in most tables
- the primary key will eliminate the need for a composite foregin key on `Duration_of_stay_at_Property` (without the primary key, you need two columns to relate to a row in `Owner_Property`)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an "owner stays" relationship.  I am going to assume that the relationship is always to a property where that the owner owns (as opposed to any old property).  That is, this may not include all time frames, because owners may also rend properties.

So, this suggests a table like `staying` with attributes for:

- owner/property primary key
- start date
- end date
- any other relevant information

This suggests that you want a single column primary key on the `owner/`property` relationship.

Comment: Actually, there is no renting part in the DB, I don't consider that. Properties won't be rented to anyone else. A person owns properties, he/she may or may not stay in any or some of them. For those properties he/she stays at, month of stay will be stored.  Sometimes a person may stay for consecutive months or skip some months. And yep, you are right. But I don't store month of stay info in Owner_property table though, it seems like a mess. I want Owner_Property table to be just a pairing between owner and property.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that Ownership (many:many mapping between owners and properties) is *independent* of who is there, when.  Make two tables.

The owner_property table should have two columns (no auto_increment); the PK should have both columns, and you probably need an index with the columns in the opposite order.  [*More discussion and tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

The other table would have the same two columns, plus something to do with the Occupancy time (or time range).  The PK and secondary indexes will depend on the queries you expect to perform.  If no one is ever in a particular property, there would be no rows for that property.  A busy property may have thousands of rows -- no relationship to the Ownership table.

(OK, I am pretty much saying what the other Answers said.)